# Prove the size of a hyperbolic angle is twice the area of its hyperbolic sector.

Tags: calculus, geometry, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I'm trying to figure out how the hyperbolic functions are derived using a unit hyperbola.

According to [this walkthrough](http://talks.isaacgreenspan.com/DerivingTheHyperbolicTrigFunctions.pdf), argument $u$ in $(\cosh(u), \sinh(u))$ should be equal to $2A$, where $A$ is the area of an intercepted hyperbolic sector from $(0,0)$ to $(\cosh(u), \sinh(u))$.

Confused as to why this is defined as such, I found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function):

> **The size of a hyperbolic angle is twice the area of its hyperbolic sector.** The hyperbolic functions *may be defined in terms of the legs of a right triangle covering this sector*.

However, I couldn't find a explanation for this anywhere. Can anyone help show me why this is?

Comment: See the last paragraph of [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409).

Comment: The middle portion of your answer is a very difficult argument to follow. I've managed to figure out the "e" definition by means of integration, but I still don't understand from your answer what necessarily implies u = 2A. I'm guessing this is somehow in the geometry of your included picture, but I would really prefer a more algebraic answer because I'm more easily convinced that way. Could you elaborate on all of this more specifically? I appreciate your work by the way, in fact your answer was one of the first I read when I started trying to figure this out and it helped get me started.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The notion of "hyperbolic angle" is really a contrived concept that is only used to better define *an analogy* between *the hyperbolic functions as a parameterization of the hyperbola* and *the trigonometric functions as a parameterization of the circle*.

The hyperbolic functions **are not** defined based on the traditional notion of an angle. They are, in fact, defined based on **the area of an intercepted arc** on the hyperbola.

To find the area of this intercepted arc using calculus and geometry, *subtract the area under the curve from 1 to some x* in quadrant I from *the triangle created from the line that connects the origin $(0,0)$ with this point $(x,\sqrt{x^2 -1})$*:

$\hskip2in$[image: Area under curve]

\begin{align}
A &= \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2 -1} - \int _1 ^x \sqrt{x^2 -1}dx \\
&= \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2 -1} - \frac{1}{2}x\sqrt{x^2 -1} + \frac{1}{2}\ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-1}) \\
2A &= \ln(x + \sqrt{x^2-1})\\
e^{2A}&= x + \sqrt{x^2-1}\\
\end{align}

At this point, we can substitute $\sqrt{x^2-1}$ with $y$ for simplicity.

\begin{align}
e^{2A}&= x + y\\
e^{2A}(x-y)&= (x+y)(x-y)\\
e^{2A}(x-y)&= x^2-y^2\\
\end{align}

Because these equations describe a unit hyperbola $x^2 - y^2 = 1$, we can make this crucial substitution and derive the $e^x$ definition.

\begin{align}
e^{2A}(x-y)&= 1\\
e^{2A}&= \frac{1}{x-y}\\
e^{-2A}&= x-y\\
\end{align}

If we add $x+y$ (which, remember, is equal to $e^{2A}$) to this equation, the $y$'s will cancel.
\begin{align}
2x &= e^{-2A} + x + y \\
2x &= e^{-2A} + e^{2A} \\
x &= \frac{e^{-2A} + e^{2A}}{2} \\
\end{align}

We can find $y$ if we calculate $(x+y) - (x-y)$ 
\begin{align}
(x+y) - (x-y) &= e^{2A} - e^{-2A} \\
2y &= e^{2A} - e^{-2A} \\
y &= \frac{e^{-2A} - e^{2A}}{2}  
\end{align}

If we treat these equations as functions themselves, we can now see where this $u = 2A$ definition comes from more evidently. Every $(x,y)$ on the graph $x^2 - y^2 = 1$ can be described in a relationship involving area $A$ times $2$ as proven above. We can substitute $2A$ with $u$ and call our argument $u$ whatever we want henceforth.

Here's [an interactive Desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/0chw5ppfei) I made to help illustrate the connection. It isn't a "formal proof", but I think its pretty cool.