# Challenging Integrals for High School Students

Tags: integration, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, big-list

I am now in my last year of high school. We have covered all the techniques useful for indefinite integration that are included in our Maths and Further Maths courses. This includes:

- Integration by parts, inspection, substitution, partial fraction decomposition
- Integration of regular and inverse trigonometric, regular and inverse hyperbolic, exponential, logarithmic, polynomial functions

I would like to have some challenging integrals to attack that are possible for me to solve at my current level of knowledge. By challenging, I mean integrals similar to the ones in [this](https://math.colorado.edu/%7Enewberry/Spring10/Integrals.pdf) document. They were generally enjoyable and very satisfying to solve. If you have an integral that you think I could do that is more challenging than those in the aforementioned link, so much the better.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: If you would like a challenge, the indefinite integrals on integration bees usually don't require advanced techniques beyond what you already know - they are just tricky. For example give this integral a shot $$\int \frac{2x^2+1}{x^3+x\ln x}dx$$

Comment: From youtube.com, you can enter in the **youtube search bar** : "integration bee".

Comment: @user2661923 would you say that the MIT integration bee questions are accessible to me?

Comment: "...are accessible to me"?  If you are asking whether you will be able to solve them, my attack strategy here is: Give a specific problem 15-20 minutes: if you can see a clear plan of attack of the problem in 15-20 minutes, then go for it.  If not, then surrender and study the answer in the youtube video.

Comment: @user2661923 thanks for your advice.

Comment: @NinadMunshi thanks again for the problem, I've solved it now. Where did you get it from?

Comment: As long as you haven't already seen a solution - try ${\int \sqrt{\tan(x)}dx}$. This one sure takes quite a while....

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I wrote it for the Berkeley integration bee

Comment: Too add one more thing - if you want to expand your methods a little, one method you could learn in addition is the Leibniz rule of integration. The simplest case is actually fairly easy to understand and it can help you solve a lot of very, very tough definite integrals. It's also referred to as "Feynman's trick". If it's your first time seeing it, it'll blow your mind

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose thank you for the reference, I'll check it out.

Comment: Have you tried the classic $\int \sec x \, dx$? The answer was found relatively late in the history of maths, and if you try to find it, you might understand why :) Still, it's not *too* difficult, and can be computed using the methods you outlined in the post.

Comment: @Joe thanks, I do know how to find that integral :)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I have one other idea: not an integral, but a differential equation: $y' = y^2 + 1$. Again, it is possible to do this only with A-level knowledge, but you'll have to be creative.

Comment: @Joe Thank you very much for your suggestions, I really appreciate them; I know how to do that too though :) Are you an A Level student?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Ok, hold on for one moment. I think I can find a real challenge for you.

Comment: How about STEP questions? Search integration here: https://stepdatabase.maths.org/database/index.html# and there are plenty of challenging problems.

Comment: To respond to an earlier comment, about 3/4 of MIT integration bee questions are soluble only using techniques from A-level Maths and FM.

Comment: STEP, MAT or if you manage to find some preliminary (yr1) calculus exam questions from Oxford (can email them). (Are you currently preparing for the STEP etc.?)

Comment: @A.Goodier many thanks for the link to the database, that is extremely helpful! And thanks for the feedback about the MIT bee q's.

Comment: @ChernSimons I'm not preparing for STEP this year but next year or the year after I think I will be. I would really appreciate it if you could email those Oxford questions to me. Could you email them to me at `mathshelper4you@gmail.com`?

Answer (score 1):

These problems are not challenging but still good to do them

1. $\int\exp(x)\bigg(\frac{1+x\ln x}{x}\bigg)\mathrm dx$
2. $\int \sin(101x) \sin^{99}(x)\mathrm dx$
3. $\int \sqrt{x-\sqrt{x^2-4}} \ \ \mathrm dx$

Play with these they are high school level.

Comment: Thank you, I will try them too.

Comment: your are welcome

Answer (score 1):

In this question, $a$ is a positive constant.

(i)        Express $\cosh a$ in terms of exponentials.

By using partial fractions, prove that $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{x^2 + 2x\cosh a + 1} \mathrm dx = \frac{a}{2 \sinh a} .$$

(ii)       Find, expressing your answers in terms of hyperbolic functions,
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2 + 2x \sinh a -1} \mathrm dx$$
and
$$\int_0^ \infty \frac{1}{x^4 +2x^2 \cosh a + 1} \mathrm dx.$$

---

Find the area of the region between the curve $y = \frac {\ln x}{x} $
and the $x$-axis, for $1 \leq x  \leq a$. What happens to this area as $a$ tends to infinity?

Find the volume of the solid obtained when the region between the curve $y = \frac{\ln x}{x}$ and the $x$-axis, for $1 \leq x \leq a$, is rotated through $2π$ radians about the $x$-axis. What happens to this volume as $a$ tends to infinity?

---

For $n = 1, 2, 3, ..., $ let

$$I_n = \int_0^1 \frac{t^{n-1}}{(t+1)^n} \mathrm dt. $$

By considering the greatest value taken by $ \frac{t}{t+1} $ for $0 \leq  t \leq 1$ show that $I_n+1 < \frac{1}{2}I_n .$

Show also that $I_{n+1} = -\frac{1}{n2^n-1}.$

Deduce that $I_n < \frac{1}{n2^n-1}$

Prove that
$$ \ln 2 = \sum_{r=1}^n \frac{1}{r 2^r} + I_{n+1}$$

and hence how that $\frac{2}{3} < \ln 2 < \frac{17}{24}.$

---

The above questions are sourced from [this](https://maths.org/step) website. All credits go to them.
If you need any more questions, please just drop a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite an integral, but a differential equation. This one definitely requires some outside of the box thinking!

---

Consider the solution $y(x)$ of the differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx}=\sqrt{1+y^{2020}}
$$
determined by the initial data $y(0)=0$.

Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $y^{(n)}(0)$ is an integer. Then find the first non-zero value of $y^{(n)}(0)$ with $n>1$.

Comment: I've just spent the last few days trying to solve the differential equation first, and it turns out it doesn't have an elementary solution! It is certainly trickier than i expected.

Comment: Where did you get this question from? (I won't cheat; I'm just curious.)

Comment: @A-LevelStudent It's from a Christmas challenge from Loughborough University. Hint: you don't actually need to find an elementary solution for the differential equation. Use the fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I only just saw your comment, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for integrals, here is an integral! This one I found quite challenging, but perhaps you'll find a more elegant way of solving it than I did:
$$
\int \frac{dx}{(9-36x^2)^{3/2}} \, .
$$
NB this definitely *can* be solved using the methods outlined in your post.

Comment: Done that now, thanks, it was quite an interesting one. Forgive me for asking, but are you also an A Level student, or are you and undergraduate or beyond? You seem pretty familiar with the syllabus.

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Indeed I am! I'm a Year 13 student taking A-level further maths. I'm considering taking a gap year, given how disruptive things have been recently...

Comment: Wow, so am I! You know a lot for A Level FM and M, how do you know it all? Btw, for tough integration q's I'm using the MIT Integration Bee qualifier exam, you may be interested in them too. Which options are you doing? Further pure? Mechanics? Decision? Stats?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent Further pure and statistics. I study a lot of maths in my free time as a hobby project. I am especially interested in analysis; a lot of my knowledge comes from reading Stack Exchange threads, and Wikipedia articles. I also have a copy of Michael Spivak's *Calculus*, which goes into a lot more detail about the underlying theory behind what we learn at A-level. Using this book, I've reached a much deeper understanding of functions, limits, continuity, and proofs of derivative rules and integration techniques. I'll be sure to check out the MIT integration Bee if I find the time.

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of calculus questions concerning hyperbolic functions:

1. Just as $\sin$ can be defined as the unique function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
   \begin{align}
   f''(x) &= \color{blue}{-}f(x) \\
   f'(x) &= 1 \\
   f(x) &= 0 \, ,
   \end{align}
   $\sinh$ can be defined as the unique function $f:\mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ satisfying
   \begin{align}
   f''(x) &= \color{red}{+}f(x) \\
   f'(x) &= 1 \\
   f(x) &= 0 \, .
   \end{align}
   Derive the exponential form of hyperbolic sine by solving the above equation.
2. The classical way to define $\sinh$ is via the 'unit hyperbola':
   [image: The geometric interpations of the hyperbolic functions]
   If the region OPR has an area of $t/2$, then the $x$- and $y$-coordinates are, respectively, $\cosh t$ and $\sinh t$. (If you're interested in the details of how hyperbolic functions can be defined using a hyperbola, then see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/757091/alternative-definition-of-hyperbolic-cosine-without-relying-on-exponential-funct/757241#757241).) If however you define $\sinh$ and $\cosh$ using exponentials, then it is possible to prove that the shaded area is equal to $t/2$, given that $OQ = \cosh t$ and $PQ = \sinh t$. Prove this using integration. You may need to use hyperbolic identities to simplify your answer.
3. The graph of $\cosh$ has a curious property. For any interval $[a,b]$, the area under the graph is equal to the length of the arc connecting the points $(a,\cosh a)$ and $(b,\cosh b)$. Prove this using the formula
   $$
   \text{arc length} = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{1+\left(f'(x)\right)^2} \, dx \, ,
   $$
   where $y=f(x)$ is the graph of the function in question. (Here, $f=\cosh$.) And if you're interested in seeing why the arc length formula works, then see [here](https://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/classes/calcii/arclength.aspx).

Comment: Thanks Joe! I already discovered number 3 for myself a few months ago, but I'll have a go at the other 2.

Answer (score 1):

This one's really nice.

$$\int\frac{1}{x^7-x}\text{ }dx$$

There's a clever trick that can save you from a tedious partial fraction decomposition. Can you find it?

Comment: I got the trick (I think the one you mean) and have done it, thanks! The trick I used was the substitution $u=x^6$, or equivakently multiplying the tip and bottom by $x^5$. Is that the one you meant?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent nice!

Comment: @A-LevelStudent that's not the one I had in mind, but it certainly offers another way to approach the problem!

Comment: Oh, what was the trick you had in mind?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent I think it would be better if you discovered it yourself. I'll give you a hint, but if you insist, I'll give you the trick directly.

Hint: factor something out from the denominator.

Comment: Fine, I'll try again :)

Comment: Is your trick factoring out $x^7$ from the denominator and rewriting it in the numerator as $x^{-7}$?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent you found it! Awesome job!!

Comment: Thank you very much :) It's a wonderful trick, I'll remember it.

Answer (score 1):

To add yet another answer to your question, here are two integrals which are challenging, but their solutions are not *too* messy:
\begin{align}
&\int \sin(\log_2(x)) \, dx \, , \\[5pt]
&\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{e^{2x}+1}} \, .
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks Joe. Did you take the Advanced Extension Award in Mathematics?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: Nope. Did you take it?

Comment: I'm taking it tomorrow. You could almost certainly have done it too I think, judging from your questions and answers, was there any particular reason that you didn't?

Comment: @A-LevelStudent: I didn't really consider it, and I don't think my school did much to advertise that it was available. But good luck tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks! It went really well.