# How do you prove these definitions of $\cosh$ are equivalent?

Tags: trigonometry, hyperbolic-geometry, special-relativity

I am reading the book, Geometry of Special Relativity, by Tevian Gray.

In the introductory chapter to hyperbolic geometry, he states that the definition:

$$
\cosh(\beta) = \frac{e^\beta + e^{-\beta}}{2}
$$

is equivalent to the definition:
$$
\cosh(\beta) = x/\rho,
$$
where
$$
\rho = x^2-y^2
$$

These definitions make intuitive sense, but I'm not sure how to prove their equivalency.
For context, I am an 18-year-old just out of high school, with a good grasp of simple variable calculus, but no exposure to college math yet.

Comment: Small thing: did you meant to write $\rho^2=x^2-y^2$?

Comment: Its based off the pythagorean identity for hyperbolic geometry $x^2-y^2=cosh^2(\beta)-sinh^2(\beta)=1$ one direction of equivalence is easier than the other, simply multiply both sides by $x$. The hard directions would require taylor series expansion similar to the proof of Eulers Identity.

Comment: What is $x$ ?? What is $y$ ??

Comment: @K.defaoite I am assuming $x=cosh(\beta)$ and $y=sinh(\beta)=cosh'(\beta)$

Comment: See, for instance, [this answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/757241/409).

Answer (score 4):

The hyperbolic functions $\cosh$ and $\sinh$ are defined by
$$
\cosh(\beta) = \frac{e^{\beta}+e^{-\beta}}{2},
\qquad
\sinh(\beta) = \frac{e^{\beta}-e^{-\beta}}{2}
$$
and satisfy the identity $\cosh(\beta)^2 - \sinh(\beta)^2 = 1.$

Now consider the hyperbola $x^2-y^2=\rho^2$ and rewrite it as
$$
\left(\frac{x}{\rho}\right)^2 - \left(\frac{y}{\rho}\right)^2 = 1.
$$
It has a clear similarity to the hyperbolic identity above and we can make the following identifications:
$$
\frac{x}{\rho}=\cosh(\beta),
\qquad
\frac{y}{\rho}=\sinh(\beta).
$$